# Leaks in TCP connections or buffer

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, port

On Windows Server 2019, my c# program, after several days of runnig faces the exception: "**An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full**" (when it tries to open TPC connection with other program on the same machine). The programs perform this communication countless times during their run, but suddenly they can't. All I have to do is restart the programs, and everything returns to normal ...for a few weeks. There are many explanations for this exception on the Internet, but when I check connections by **netstats**, the number in the whole system is about 200 and in the TIME_WAIT state there are only a few. Could there be another cause than wasting dynamic ports or too big TcpTimedWaitDelay?
Thank you for the advice

Comment: are you closing sockets properly? Probably there is no TIME_WAIT sockets but socket handles are not released and returned back to the OS

Comment: I'm trying to encapsulate everything in using, but maybe I have a bug somewhere. Can any tools be used to find out? Any way to watch the growth of these socket "handles"? I have limited testing options on a given computer, it is with the customer.

Comment: try to google for `find leaking socket c#` not sure that such tool exists. However you may run the service on your computer and create a dummy test client to load the service. This allow you to use VS memory profiler and check for leaked objects (having the service running under VS debug)

Comment: I second @oleksa. Best shot is to rig up a "test lab" and basically do a crash test. Setup a system, then put load on it while monitoring the relevant markers.

Comment: TIME_WAIT occurs when both the client and server simultaneously tries to close a connection.  TCP is reliable which means every command gets an ACK. When both ends of a TCP connection closes at the same time one side closes before the other so one of the ACKs never gets sent.  Then Net puts the connection into a TIME_WAIT state when one side of the connection is waiting for the ACK.  You should only close a connection from the client side and not the server side.